# Where can I ask about setting a background on my computer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have two monitors and I have a separate slideshow prepared for both. I have looked online and seen only how to set one background per monitor not slideshows.

I would like to ask for help doing this within the Stack Exchange network, but I am not sure which site to use. Would this be on-topic anywhere, and if so, can someone recommend the best one for me?

Comment: I retagged this as a [tag:site-recommendation] since your title seems to be looking for that. I also made some substantial edits to the post. Let me know if they aren't in-line with what you were originally looking for, and if they weren't, be sure to read the [help/on-topic] to see what we can help you with here.

Comment: Sounds like it would fit on Super User.

Comment: This type of question would belong on [su].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General computer usage questions, particularly for Windows based machines, are generally best on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). The exception would be when you think the task you are trying to accomplish requires one or more pieces of software that you don't have and you are trying to pick which software to use. In that case [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be helpful. In the case of some operating systems there are OS specific sites such as [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and for other Linux/BSD/Etc. there is [Unix + Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).